# Dropdown menu display/hide

Tags: css

For some reason, I can hide the sub-menu of my project by way of the CSS "display:none" code, but cannot get it to reappear by hovering over the "ONLINE TRADING" link as per Line 98 of my CSS code. It's my guess that the solution to my dilemma is hiding in plain sight, but beyond mt perception.

```css
.nav_wrapper {/*---MAIN NAVIGATION WRAPPER---*/
position: fixed;
z-index: 9999;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 90px;
width: 100%;
transition: top .1s ease-out;
text-align: left;  
}

nav {
margin: 0 auto;   
}

.scroll {
top: 0
}

.no-scroll {
top: 0;
z-index: 9999
}

main {
margin: 0 auto;
font-size: 12px
}

.menu-link {
display: none
}

.menu {
height: 90px;
background: #FFFFFF;
transition: all 1.0s ease;
padding: 0 0 0 0;  
}

.menu ul {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
text-align: right;
}

.menu ul li {
padding: 0;
}

.menu>ul>li {
display: inline-block;  
}

.menu ul li a {
padding: 60px 10px 0px 0px;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;    
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: left;
-o-transition: .3s;
-ms-transition: .3s;
-moz-transition: .3s;
-webkit-transition: .3s;
transition: .3s
}

.menu ul li.hover>a {
color: #990100;
font-size: 12pt;
}

.menu ul li>a {
font-size: 12pt;
margin-top: 0;
}

.menu ul ul>li a {
padding: 10px 10px;
height: auto;
}

.menu ul ul>li a:hover {
padding: 10px 10px;
height: auto;
background: #990100;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

.menu ul ul>li  {
display:none;
}

.menu ul ul>li:hover   {
display:block;
}
```

```html
    <div class="nav_wrapper"> 
  <div class="spinner-master">
    <input type="checkbox" id="spinner-form" />
    <label for="spinner-form" class="spinner-spin">
    <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
    <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
    <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
    </label>
  </div>

    <nav id="menu" class="menu"><div onclick="location.href='index.html';" class="headertablelogo"></div>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#top" target="_self">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#onlinetrading" target="_self">Online Trading</a></li>      
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#lngbuyers">Marketplace for LNG Buyers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#lngsellersbuyers">Marketplace for LNG Sellers</a></li>
        <li><a href="traders">Marketplace for LNG Traders</a></li>
        </ul>         
      <li><a href="#counterpartyrisk" target="_self">Counterparty Risk</a></li>
      <li><a href="newsarchives" target="_self">News </a></li>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="traders">News Archives</a></li>
        </ul>  
      <li><a href="#blog" target="_self">Blog </a></li>
      <li><a href="#team" target="_self">Team </a></li>
      <li><a id="loginbutton" href="https://live.redwoodmarkets.com" target="_blank">LOGIN </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Moribund/381ntcmx/15/

Comment: Hi - did you know you can embed CSS, JS and HTML directly into your quesiton? look at the little `<>` document button.

Comment: if you want `show hide` menu than use `jquery`

Comment: Your jsfiddle link is broken and there is no submenu

Comment: @Justcode take off the `][1]` from the end of the URL and it works (https://jsfiddle.net/Moribund/381ntcmx/15/)

Comment: try this link to submenu ['submenu on hover'](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_hover)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your css as follows,

```css
.nav_wrapper {/*---MAIN NAVIGATION WRAPPER---*/
position: fixed;
z-index: 9999;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 90px;
width: 100%;
transition: top .1s ease-out;
text-align: left;  
}

nav {
margin: 0 auto;   
}

.scroll {
top: 0
}

.no-scroll {
top: 0;
z-index: 9999
}

main {
margin: 0 auto;
font-size: 12px
}

.menu-link {
display: none
}

.menu {
height: 90px;
background: #ffffff;
transition: all 1.0s ease;
padding: 0 0 0 0;  
}

.menu ul {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
text-align: right;
}

/*---Set main menu item will be display in line--*/
.menu ul li {
display: inline-block;  
}

/*---Set main menu item background color on hovering with mouse--*/
.menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #f95250;
}

/*---Set main menu link properties--*/
.menu ul li a, visited {
padding: 60px 10px 0px 0px;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;    
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: left;
-o-transition: .3s;
-ms-transition: .3s;
-moz-transition: .3s;
-webkit-transition: .3s;
transition: .3s
}

/*---Set main menu link properties on hovering with mouse--*/
.menu ul li a:hover {
color: White;
font-size: 12pt;
text-decoration: none;
}

/*---Display submenu on hovering on main menu item--*/
.menu ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
}

/*---Set submenu hide initialy--*/
.menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #990100;
}

/*---Set submenu item properties--*/
.menu ul ul li {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/*---Set submenu link properties--*/
.menu ul ul li a, visited {
color: black;
}

/*---Set submenu link properties on hovering with mouse--*/
.menu ul ul li a:hover {
   color: white;
   display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="nav_wrapper"> 
  <div class="spinner-master">
    <input type="checkbox" id="spinner-form" />
    <label for="spinner-form" class="spinner-spin">
    <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
    <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
    <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
    </label>
  </div>

    <nav id="menu" class="menu"><div onclick="location.href='index.html';" class="headertablelogo"></div>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#top" target="_self">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#onlinetrading" target="_self">Online Trading</a>          
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#lngbuyers">Marketplace for LNG Buyers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#lngsellersbuyers">Marketplace for LNG Sellers</a></li>
        <li><a href="traders">Marketplace for LNG Traders</a></li>
       </ul>             
      </li>      
           
      <li><a href="#counterpartyrisk" target="_self">Counterparty Risk</a></li>
      <li><a href="newsarchives" target="_self">News </a> 
       <ul>
        <li><a href="traders">News Archives</a></li>
       </ul>     
      </li>
      
      <li><a href="#blog" target="_self">Blog </a></li>
      <li><a href="#team" target="_self">Team </a></li>
      <li><a id="loginbutton" href="https://live.redwoodmarkets.com" target="_blank">LOGIN </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
```

Add Submenu `ul` tag inside main menu `li` tag

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

If you already hidden the li how can you hover it.

In the below code you hidden the li.

```
.menu ul ul>li  {
    display:none;
}
```

In the below code you written to display by hovering the li.

```
.menu ul ul>li:hover   {
    display:block;
}
```

Change the code if you hover the ul then display li.I am not sure in CSS but u can use jquery.
Jquery code.

```
$(".menu ul ul:hover").hover(function(){
        $(".menu ul ul>li").css("display", "block");
        });
});
```